# Как убрать пробелы в wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

Как убрать эти два пробела, в коде редактора не вижу пробелов.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот в редакторе нет пустоты в начале файла:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: До `header.php` в частности, и файлов темы вообще, загружаются плагины. Ищите проблему в них путём последовательного отключения. Если не найдёте - то смотрите другие файлы темы, которые загружаются раньше `header.php` - `functions.php`, `index.php`.

Answer (score 0):

Это или [BOM](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%80_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8_%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2) (что наиболее вероятно) или неверные вызовы функций в хедер.
ВОМ можно поискать с помощью [скрипта от ЮБ](http://blog.portal.kharkov.ua/2008/04/08/find_bom/).

Comment: Думаете тот редактор `BOM` за два символа перевода строки посчитал? :)

Comment: @gil9red именно так и бывает, тоже приходилось сталкиваться с такой проблемой из-за BOM-элементов